# what are various PHP attack and how to protect for attack

Tags: php, security

What are php input attack,and how to protect from input attack

i allow user to enter data from 11 input field

i need to know `php` attacks and how can i protect from attack can someone give me idea about php attack's

a how can i protect from user input do i need to create `php` function are and validate function using `jquery`

can someone give me idea attacks and prevention

user input are saved to `sql` after processing

Comment: There are not many attacks that aim to exploit vulnerabilities specific to PHP. Most vulnerabilities in PHP applications are rather generic to web applications per se and can also be found in applications written in other languages. However, applications written in plain PHP are more prone to some kind of vulnerabilities as they don’t provide certain abstractions or framework capabilities out of the box like other languages/frameworks do.

Comment: It appears your knowledge level is really low, you want to validate a php function using jquery - that just screams "no". Attacks are successful when  people who don't know much create stupid things - you can only protect against those by learning more and not doing stupid things. Other than that, PHP doesn't have any vulnerabilities per-se.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-specific bugs aren't really a huge issue. What you should worry about are generic input-poisoning attacks.

These include:

- SQL Injection
- XSS
- Shell script escaping

There are probably others that I've forgotten, but that's where you should start. I would also advise asking more specific questions. Asking simply about security in PHP is much too broad of a subject.

A good resource for PHP security however would be [OWASP](http://lp.checkmarx.com/php-code-security/?utm_source=google-ppc&utm_content=46422612231&utm_medium=cpc&utm_keyword=owasp%20php%20security&utm_campaign=Search-php-othercountries-west(klog)&utm_query=%7BQueryString%7D&leadsource=PPC&lead_sub_source__c=google&gclid=CjwKEAjwsZyqBRCT1aq6qcD53DQSJACcen4CmDi7v25EAIsUW2zXJcJCd0Ny3Mts86AIolYTvk01fRoCQtjw_wcB)